# Counting the number of times an item appears in a column in a pandas dataframe based on unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of people emailing potential clients and each other with timestamp and email_ID. What I am trying to do is to summarize it into a dataframe of the count of number of emails each person has sent adn each person has received. 
df_in below is the simulated dataset of input.
df_out is the output I want (I want it sorted with the highest sender count, followed by highest received count).
I have tried to use groupby and size and tried three different ways (df1, df2 and df3). However, I am not even able to get the send count correct (as in df_out). How do i do this? python code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.DataFrame({
'sender':['Able Boy','Able Boy','Able Boy','Mark L. Taylor','Mark L. Taylor','Mark L. Taylor','scott kirk','scott kirk','scott kirk','scott kirk'],
'receiver':['Toni Z. Zapata','Mark Angel','Johnny C. Cash','paul a boyd','michelle fam','debbie bradford','Mark Angel','Johnny C. Cash','Able Boy','Mark L. Taylor'],
'timeContact':[911929000000,911929000000,910228000000,911497000000,911497000000,911932000000,914261000000,914267000000,914269000000,914276000000],
'email_ID':['<A34E5R>','<A34E5R>','<B34E5R>','<C34E5R>','<C34E5R>','<C36E5R>','<C36E5A>','<C36E5B>','<C36E5C>','<C36E5D>']
})

print("\ndf_in is:")
print(df_in)

df_out = pd.DataFrame({
'person':['scott kirk','Able Boy','Mark L. Taylor','Mark Angel','Toni Z. Zapata','Johnny C. Cash','paul a boyd','michelle fam','debbie bradford'],
'number_send':[4,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'number_received':[0,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1]
})

print()
print("\ndf_out is:")
print(df_out)

df1 = df_in.groupby(['email_ID','sender']).size()
print()
print("\ndf1 is:")
print(df1)

df2 = df_in.groupby(['sender']).size()
print()
print("\ndf2 is:")
print(df2)

df3 = df_in.groupby(['sender','email_ID']).size()
print()
print("\ndf3 is:")
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at `nunique` instead of `count` or `size`:

```
(pd.merge(df_in.groupby('sender').email_ID.nunique(),  # count email sent by ID
         df_in.groupby('receiver').email_ID.nunique(), # count email received by ID
         left_index=True,                              # merge on sender  
         right_index=True,                             # merge on receiver
         how='outer')
 .fillna(0)                                            # replace missing with Nan
 .rename(columns={'email_ID_x':'number_send',          # rename columns as needed
                  'email_ID_y':'number_received'})
)
```

Output:

```
                 number_send  number_received
Able Boy                 2.0              1.0
Johnny C. Cash           0.0              2.0
Mark Angel               0.0              2.0
Mark L. Taylor           2.0              1.0
Toni Z. Zapata           0.0              1.0
debbie bradford          0.0              1.0
michelle fam             0.0              1.0
paul a boyd              0.0              1.0
scott kirk               4.0              0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the column person with `unique` values from both column sender and receiver. then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) this column with the [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) from sender and receiver. Finally `fillna` and `sort_values` on the two columns of counts with the parameter ascending=False

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'person': pd.np.unique(df_in[['sender','receiver']].values.flatten())})
df_out['number_send'] = df_out.person.map(df_in.drop_duplicates(subset=['sender','email_ID'])
                                               .sender.value_counts())
df_out['number_received'] = df_out.person.map(df_in.receiver.value_counts())
df_out = df_out.fillna(0).sort_values(by=['number_send', 'number_received'], ascending=False)\
               .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df_out)
            person  number_send  number_received
0       scott kirk          4.0              0.0
1         Able Boy          2.0              1.0
2   Mark L. Taylor          2.0              1.0
3   Johnny C. Cash          0.0              2.0
4       Mark Angel          0.0              2.0
5   Toni Z. Zapata          0.0              1.0
6  debbie bradford          0.0              1.0
7     michelle fam          0.0              1.0
8      paul a boyd          0.0              1.0
```

Comment: Both the solutions are not counting "Able Boy" correctly for example. He sent two emails "<A34E5R>" and "<B34E5R>". But had copied one of them to two people. Hence, it appeared thrice. So, the column "email_ID" needs to be factored in correctly. To get the answer 2 for him for example, rather than 3.

Comment: @AlhpaDelta I added `drop_duplicates` with the subset to get your expected output. I did not get it first it was for unique email_ID. if you have doubt concerning receiver being twice for the same email_ID, then add also drop_duplicates but with `subset=['receiver', 'email_ID']`

Answer (score 1):

**Use `melt`** (*edited to correctly to account values of columns `email_ID`*)
`melt` columns `sender`, `receiver` and do `groupby` on it with `nunique`. Next, `unstack` and `sum` on index level=1

```
df1 = df_in.melt(id_vars='email_ID', value_vars=['sender', 'receiver'])
df_new = (df1.groupby([*df1.columns], sort=False)
             .email_ID.nunique().unstack(1).sum(level=1))

Out[250]:
variable         sender  receiver
value
Able Boy            2.0       1.0
Toni Z. Zapata      0.0       1.0
Mark Angel          0.0       2.0
Johnny C. Cash      0.0       2.0
Mark L. Taylor      2.0       1.0
paul a boyd         0.0       1.0
michelle fam        0.0       1.0
debbie bradford     0.0       1.0
scott kirk          4.0       0.0
```